# JAXBContext Managing

Tags: java, jaxb, java-ee-6

I have to generate a lot of xml snippets and store the into my database for later (re-)use.
JaxB works fine, but i some questions came up:

1. Should i have one JAXBContext for the whole application or for each response dto one? I would keep the context in a static variable in each root dto object. (initialized once)
2. Is there no way to inject an marshaller in JEE6?

I want to keep the boilerplate code as small as possible.

greetings
m

PS: XStream worked fine too, but i want to stick to the standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, you need only one JAXBContext
- You can always inject marshaller. (Best way is to use Spring)

  ```
   <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
       <property name="classesToBeBound">
          <list>
              <value>com.package.YourClass</value>
           </list>
      </property>
  </bean>
  ```

I don't properly understand what you mean be "sticking to standards", but you could give a look at [JIBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/). It generally provides better performance than JaxB

Comment: Thanks! That is very good hint! As i see this example i could accomplish the same functionality with (Produces, Inject) Annotations without introducing spring. I meant to use as few third party libraries as possible and use the provided server libs.

Comment: @Anshu - JAXB is a standard JSR-222 (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) with multiple implementations (Metro, MOXy, etc).  Because it is a standard it is the default binding layer for JAX-WS and JAX-RS and an impl is included in JDK/JRE since Java SE 6.